# Split input string into single words, check the value of the word if specific value exists create variable keeping same index as original string

Tags: python, variables, split

I am working on a program that will take a sentence, split it into individual words then check each word for specific values. What I want to happen is if the specific value exists in the input string, create a variable with that value while keeping the same index as the original input string for sentence structure when joining them back together.

Here is my code so far, I the split & rejoin sussed just cant seem to figure out how to go about the rest of it..

```
#emsg = "Word not found."

c_e = raw_input("Text: ")
wordblocks = c_e.split(' ',)

wordblocksrev = ' '.join(wordblocks[::1])

print wordblocks
print wordblocksrev
```

Edit: wordblocksrev refers to "wordblocks" after the words have been replaced & put back into a string for the output, so the output will be results of corresponding dictionary words in the same index. I've already figured the word swap out.

Example:

```
text = input("Enter text: ")
#For arguments sake the user enters "I have a black dog"
words = text.split(' ')
#["I", "have", "a", "black", "dog"]

#set variable with each value
wordblock1 = "I"
wordblock2 = "have"
wordblock3 = "three"
wordblock4 = "black"
wordblock5 = "dogs"

altwords = ["You", "had", "four", "white", "cats"]
#if "have" in text, replace with "had" (same index separate lists)
#if "black" in text, replace with "white"
#I want to hold each word as a variable, change some words, join back together so that it makes sense as a sentence
```

apologies for any bad code, im pretty new to python & still learning the basics. TIA

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: If the list is supposed to be reversed that would be wordblocksrev = ' '.join(wordblocks[::1])  (i.e. -1 rather than +1).  But, not clear from description why you want things reversed.

Comment: You might want to consider not assigning the specific words to variables and just using a for-loop to modify the list

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out, heres the code incase anyone else finds use in it. Probably a much better way of doing this but its fast enough for me & does the job.

```
txt = input("Enter sentence: ")
split = txt.split(' ')

collectedwords = []

if not txt:
    print("No input entered.")
    wordblock1 = ""
else:
    wordblock1 = split[0]
    wordtest1 = wordblock1
    if wordtest1 == 'black':
        wordr1 = wordtest1.replace("black", "white")
        collectedwords.append(wordr1) 
    else:
        wordr1 = split[0]
        collectedwords.append(wordr1)

if "" in txt:
    wordblock2 = ""
else:
    wordblock2 = split[1]
    wordtest2 = wordblock2
    if wordtest2 == 'blue':
        wordr2 = wordtest2.replace("blue", "green")
        collectedwords.append(wordr2)
    else:
        wordr2 = split[1]
        collectedwords.append(wordr2)

reform = ' '.join(collectedwords)

print(txt)
print("Collected Words:", collectedwords)
print("\nReformed Words:", reform)
```